# Customize table structure in XlstListViewWebPart

Tags: 2010, xslt, branding

I need to modify the structure of the HTML rendered by the XsltListViewWebPart in the default AllItems.aspx SharePoint page. Specifically, I need to separate the column headings into its own table and the data cells into its own table.

I have customized an Empty Data View web part before and it was very simple since the structure of the table was in the code of the page. For the XsltListViewWebPart the table structure seems to be hidden somewhere else.

How can I change the table structure of this XLWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wabpart uses XSL transformation. Basically, it uses main.xsl file to render HTML. You can find this file into 14 folder. But I donot recomend to do changes in this file. The best solution is to coppy main.xsl, rename it and then add reference to a new file in the webpart property or list definition. Also you can use [SharePoint designer to make changes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-view-using-sharepoint-designer-HA010379079.aspx). In this case xsl for transformation includes into webpart markup.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have a web part exactly for this need, called [Item Lister Web Part](http://www.spwp.net/web-parts/item-lister-web-part.aspx). You can check that out.

Have a nice day...